# How can i make the DC motor spin different directions according to which button i press

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

this is my first project on the raspberry pi. i am using 4 wheels connected to DC motors.i want 2 to go forward and backward and 2 left and right how can i make the motors spin in different directions depending on the button i click

Comment: I would try negative value to spin in different direction. But first I would check documentation for module which you use to controlo motors

Comment: Thank u Will check